# Printing a name in Standard format

Tags: c, string

I am trying to develop a basic program that takes your name and provides the output in standard format. The problem is that I want the user to have an option of not adding the middle name.

For Example: Carl Mia Austin gives me C. M. Austin but I want that even if the Input is Carl Austin it should give me C. Austin without asking the user if they have a middle name or not. 
So, Is there a way or function which could automatically detect that??

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char first[32], middle[20], last[20];

    printf("Enter full name: ");
    scanf("%s %s %s", first, middle, last);
    printf("Standard name: ");
    printf("%c. %c. %s\n", first[0], middle[0], last);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As currently written, `scanf("%s %s %s", first, middle, last);` expects 3 parts to be typed and will wait until the user types them.

You want to read a line of input with `fgets()` and scan that for name parts with `sscanf` and count how many parts were converted:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char first[32], middle[32], last[32];
    char line[32];

    printf("Enter full name: ");
    fflush(stdout);  // make sure prompt is output
    if (fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin)) {
        // split the line into parts.
        // all buffers have the same length, no need to protect the `%s` formats
        *first = *middle = *last = '\0';
        switch (sscanf(line, "%s %s %[^\n]", first, middle, last)) {
        case EOF: // empty line, unlikely but possible if stdin contains '\0'
        case 0:  // no name was input
            printf("No name\n");
            break;
        case 1:  // name has a single part, like Superman
            printf("Standard name: %s\n", first);
            strcpy(last, first);
            *first = '\0';
            break;
        case 2:  // name has 2 parts
            printf("Standard name: %c. %s\n", first[0], middle);
            strcpy(last, middle);
            *middle = '\0';
            break;
        case 3:  // name has 3 or more parts
            printf("Standard name: %c. %c. %s\n", first[0], middle[0], last);
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Note that names can be a bit more versatile in real life: think of foreign names with multibyte characters, or even simply `William Henry Gates III`, also known as Bill Gates.  The above code handles the latter, but not this one: `Éléonore de Provence`, the young wife of Henry III, King of England, 1223 - 1291.

Comment: The only problemI se in this code is semantic @chqrlie. In case the person doesn't have a middle name, but enters the first and last names only, what was meant as the last name gets interpreted as `middle`.

Comment: @user3078414: I am not sure what you mean in your comment.  If the user enters a name with only 2 parts, only `first` and `middle` are converted by `sscanf()` and the *standard name* is printed as the initial of the `first` and the full `middle`, which is really the last name.  Renaming these 3 arrays `part1`, `part2` and `part3` would reduce potential confusion.

Comment: Thanks for your reaction, @chqrlie. I am thinking of the code possibly organizing data and making it ready to copy into whichever database needed. I don't believe someone would need such a code just for feeding `printf()`. (-:

Answer (score 0):

You could use `isspace` and look for spaces in the name:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void)
{
    char first[32], middle[32], last[32];
    int count=0;
    int i = 0;
    printf("Enter full name: ");
    scanf(" %[^\n]s",first);
    for (i = 0; first[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        if (isspace(first[i]))
            count++;
    }
    if (count == 1) {
        int read = 0;
        int k=0;
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            if (isspace(first[j]))
                read++;
            if (read > 0) {
                last[k]=first[j];
                k++;
            }
        }
        last[k+1] = '\0';
    }
    printf("Standard name: ");
    printf("%c. %s\n", first[0], last);

    return 0;
}
```

Test

```
Enter full name: Carl Austin
Standard name: C.  Austin
```

Comment: I suppose you should also test what happens with two first names.

Comment: There is a stray "s" in your `scanf` pattern. But maybe it would be better to use `fgets` instead anyway.